# Can I add rules to firestore using cloud firestore REST API?

Tags: api, rest, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have 40 collections that needs to be created for d/f clients, this is so tedious to do it manually therefore I used cloud firesotre api to add the collections and I want to be able to add the rules programmtically too using REST API.

I don't know how I should be adding the rules using REST API, I have searched the google doc but haven't found any.

Is there an API that will enable me add the firestore rules programmatically using cloud firestore REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [REST API for managing the security rules in a Firebase project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rest). This allows you to create rule sets, which should match your use-case.

Comment: Hey Frank, I wanted to implement this using Firebase Rules API Client Library for .NET -- using Google.Apis.FirebaseRules.v1 --, and I am confused on how to call the method to create the firestore rules. Can you please help?

Comment: If you're having trouble getting the API to work, I recommend posting a new question with the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).